# Does this code follow the definition of recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a piece of code which I am doubting it as a implementation of recursion by its definition. My understanding is that the code must call itself, the exact same function. I also question whether writing the code this way adds additional overhead which can be seen with the use of recursion. What are your thoughts?

```
class dhObject
{
public:
   dhObject** children;
   int numChildren;
   GLdouble linkLength; //ai 
   GLdouble theta; //angle of rot about the z axis
   GLdouble twist; //about the x axis
   GLdouble displacement; // displacement from the end point of prev along z
   GLdouble thetaMax;
   GLdouble thetaMin;
   GLdouble thetaInc;
   GLdouble direction;

   dhObject(ifstream &fin)
   {
      fin >> numChildren >> linkLength >> theta >> twist >> displacement >> thetaMax >> thetaMin;
      //std::cout << numChildren << std::endl;
      direction = 1;
      thetaInc = 1.0;
      if (numChildren > 0)
      {
         children = new dhObject*[numChildren];
         for(int i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
         {
            children[i] = new dhObject(fin);
         }
      }
   }

   void traverse(void)
   {
      glPushMatrix();
      //draw move initial and draw
      transform();
      draw();
      //draw children
      for(int i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
      {
         children[i]->traverse();
      }
      glPopMatrix();
   }

   void update(void)
   {
      //Update the animation, if it has finished all animation go backwards
      if (theta <= thetaMin)
      {
         thetaInc = 1.0;
      } else if (theta >= thetaMax)
      {
         thetaInc = -1.0;
      }
      theta += thetaInc;
      //std::cout << thetaMin << " " << theta << " " << thetaMax << std::endl;
      for(int i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
      {
         children[i]->update();
      }
   }

   void draw(void)
   {
      glPushMatrix();
      glColor3f (0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
      glutSolidCube(0.1);
      glPopMatrix();
   }

   void transform(void)
   {
      //Move in the correct way, R, T, T, R
      glRotatef(theta, 0, 0, 1.0);
      glTranslatef(0,0,displacement);
      glTranslatef(linkLength, 0,0);
      glRotatef(twist, 1.0,0.0,0.0);
   }
};
```

Comment: pls snip your code down to only the relevant parts in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since you have certain functions calling themselves. By definition that is *direct recursion*. You could also have *indirect recursion* if you had function `A()` calling function `B()`, function `B()` in turn (directly or indirectly) calling function `A()` again.

Comment: Are they really calling **themselves** though?

Comment: Where does he have functions calling themselves? He has another object that calls this function, but it is not `this->callMyFuction()`.

Comment: In this case - yes, they are actually calling themselves, since *this* is of type `dhObject*`.

Comment: My C++ is not great, but even if the same exact function is called, it's called as part of a different object, so it doesn't really call itself as far as I can see.

Comment: Same object, but different instance. Does not that make a difference? - I can see why he is asking now...

Comment: The constructor is calling itself through `new dhObject`. `update` calls `update`, the same for traverse. Basically, whenever you define something (eg. function `update()`) in terms of the same object, you have recursion.

Comment: Every member function has an implicit *this* parameter. So although it is called as `functionImpl( someOtherInstance, parameter )` instead of `functionImpl( thisInstance, parameter )` is still calls *itself*, just the implicit parameter differs.

Comment: Thanks sharptooth for your explanation. Would you see potential overhead caused by using this for something that might be small (4 dh objects each with 1-2 other dh objects)? Would the g++ compiler not attempt to optimise this into a loop?

Comment: @dekz: In order to find whether the optimization takes place you need to examine assembly code emitted. Using recursion with small depth is usually okay - overhead will be minimal, however the code will not be adaptable to biffer input - once the input is too big it will incur stack overflow and just crash.

Answer (score 6):

This is a matter of definition/nitpicking. In this C function:

```
void traverse( tree * t ) {
    if ( t != 0 ) {
        traverse( t->right );
        traverse( t->left );
    }
}
```

Is the function recursive? I would say yes, even though it is being called on different objects. So I would say your code is also recursive. To take an even more extreme example:

```
unsigned int f( unsigned int n ) {
    if ( n = 0 ) {
       return 0; 
    }
    else {
       return f( n - 1 );   // XXX
    }
}
```

The thing the function is being called on at XXX is obviously not the same thing it was originally called on. But I think everyone would agree this is a recursive function.

Comment: for the definition of recursion it does not matter on which object the function is called or which parameters are passed. The only constraint is that you have to (directly or indirectly) call the same function again before you leave it.

Comment: I agree that your examples are recursive, but in my example, the functions exist in an entirely different object. Your example calls the exact same function, mine calls a function in a different object. Isn't the definition of recursive behaviour to call the exact same function?

Comment: @dekz No they don't. In C++, functions belong to the class, not to objects.

Comment: @Neil, Oh I see, so the both functions are stored at the same memory adress? a->traverse() and b->traverse() would have the same memory address? If not then they semantically the same function?

Comment: @dekz There is no "both" there is only one function "traverse" which exists at a single unique address. There are multiple calls to this function, but a function call is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like recursion in the traverse() and update() methods with depth controlled by the physical geometry of your object collection.

If this is your actual class I would recommend a few things:

1. Check the upper bound of numChildren before using it lest someone passes in a remarkably huge number by mistake.
2. If this will be used in a threaded environment you might want to synchronize access to the child objects.
3. Consider using containers instead of allocating an array.  I don't see a destructor either so you'd leak the memory for the array storage and the children if this object gets deleted.

Comment: part of the object including the destructor was snipped as it wasn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're worried about is the overhead of recursion then the important thing is to measure how deep your stack goes. It doesn't matter whether you're working recursively or not, if your stack is 100 calls deep.

Comment: It's about 4 total objects, each with 1-2 children. So I don't think there would be excessive overhead. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes. The only problem with recursion is when you go really deep.

Answer (score 0):

Calling one of these methods(traverse or update) will have the effect of calling that same method an every child. So, the methods are not recursive. Instead, it's a recursive algorithm: it is applied recursively on the logical tree of objects.

The depth of the call stack is directly determined by the structure of the data on which the algorithm operates.

What really happens is this(pseudo code):

```
Function Traverse(object o)
{
   [do something with o]

   Foreach(object child in o.Children)
       Traverse(child);

   [do something with o]
}
```